# Compact sets in the product of topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology

Let $G_1$ be a non-compact topological space and let $G_2$ be a generic topological space. What are the compact sets in the product $G_1\times G_2$?
Surely we can take the sets of the form $K_1\times K_2$ where $K_1$ and $K_2$ are respectively compact sets of $G_1$ and $G_2$. Is this right? What are the others?

Comment: There are far, far more than that. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, every closed and bounded set is compact, and that is very different from a product of compact sets

Comment: To explain a bit on the previous comment: you cannot write the closed circle in R^2 as a product of compact sets in R.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf but at the same time every open of a finite product spaces is the product of open sets right?

Comment: What is "open of a finite product spaces"? Do you mean "open sets in a ..."?

Comment: @BigbearZzz yes, sorry

Comment: No, the remark by DBS above also applies to open circles. They're not the product of opens. The products of open sets are a __base__ of the product topology.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Last thing: so, in general, a subset of the cartesian product of two sets, say the product is $A\times B$, has not the form $A'\times B'$ where $A'\subseteq A$ and $B'\subseteq B$ right? thank you

Comment: Indeed, not even for finite $A$ and $B$. Take this with a grain of salt, but it very unlikely that you manage product spaces before clearing this up. (For instance, by drawing several pictures.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Supppose $Q$ is compact in $G_1\times G_2$.  then $\pi_1(Q)$ is compact, 
$\pi_2(Q)$ is compact (the $\pi_i$ are the canonical projections), and 
$$Q\subseteq(\pi_1(Q)\times \pi_2(Q)).$$  It is also a closed subset of these provided the factor spaces are Hausdorff.

Conversely a closed subset of a product of two compact spaces is compact. So you have this characterizatoin.  $Q$ is compact in $G_1\times G_2$ if and only if there exist $K_1$ comapact in $G_1$ and $K_2$ compact in $G_2$ so $Q\subseteq K_1\times K_2$ and $Q$ is closed therein.

Comment: Not sure, if I'm missing something, but you explicitly state that $Q$ is closed "therein", but isn't that equivalent to $Q$ being closed in $G_1\times G_2$ (since $K_1\times K_2$ is closed (in $G_1\times G_2$))?

Comment: @0xbadf00d What are you trying to say?

Comment: Does this show $G_1$ and $G_2$ are compact?